# Pandas Python create column by indexed assignment on frame with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I can not figure out how to simply/efficiently add a column to a dataframe that has a multiindex by assignment from another single level index

I can add a column to a dataframe that has a single level index as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[1, 2, 5]}, 
                  index=pd.Index(['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Echo'], name='item1_name'))
df
```

[image]

```
df_item1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[101, 102, 103, 104, 105]}, 
                  index=pd.Index(['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo'], name='item1_name'))
df_item1
```

[image]

```
df['item1_id']=df_item1['id']
df
```

[image]

What I cant figure out is how to do this on a single level of a multiindex dataframe.
e.g.

```
df_multi = pd.DataFrame({'data':[1, 2, 5, 11, 12, 15]}, 
                  index=pd.Index([('Alpha', 'X'), ('Alpha', 'Y'), ('Bravo', 'X'), 
                                  ('Bravo', 'Y'), ('Echo', 'X'), ('Echo', 'Y')], 
                                   name=('item1_name','item2_name')))

df_multi['item1_id']=df_item1['id']

df_multi
```

[image]

I just get `NaN`s as the indexes arent aligning. My big picture problem is that I am receiving data with a string name and i need to be able to replace with an integer `id` ***for both levels, item1_name and item2_name***

I have long solutions using unstack/stack/reindex etc but it all seems a very long way around and I feel i ought to be able to join on the index
If my second look up frame is this:

```
df_item2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[201, 202]}, 
                  index=pd.Index(['X', 'Y'], name='item2_name'))

df_item2
```

[image]

what I want to end up with is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `rename` here, it working by match index names with `MultiIndex names`:

```
df = (df_multi.join(df_item1.rename(columns={'id':'item1_name'}))
              .join(df_item2.rename(columns={'id':'item1_nam2'})))
print (df)
                       data  item1_name  item1_nam2
item1_name item2_name                              
Alpha      X              1         101         201
           Y              2         101         202
Bravo      X              5         102         201
           Y             11         102         202
Echo       X             12         105         201
           Y             15         105         202
```

If names of index not match, get error:

```
df_item2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[201, 202]}, 
                  index=pd.Index(['X', 'Y'], name='aaa')) <- changed name


df = (df_multi.join(df_item2.rename(columns={'id':'item1_name'})))
print (df)
```

> ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names

Comment: Thank you - i had in fact tried join but it was blowing up so I guess driver error at this end - thank you!

Comment: 1 supplementary: the join column is replicated when I use join: the output that you've posted here is that not showing the duplicated join columns for clarity or is there some pandas magic i'm missing here? Looking at the pandas join docs would suggest that duplication of join column is expected behaviour: Is there a smarter way to suppress that other than giving it a suffix during the join then dropping?

Comment: @JohnnieL - I think not, unfortuantely. suffix is added for avoid duplicated columns names, e.g. here if not use `rename` then without suffix pandas should created `id` and `id` columns, what is problem (because if select `df['id']` it return both columns)